# Default values is not fine, Default wide > English is perfect

Tags: magento-1, store-view, dropdown-attribute, multi-vendor

we have marketplace multi vendor/seller site. we gave an option for seller to update the product information through frontend.

```
"Cod" is Attribute Label and "cod_available" is attribute code
```

Cod attribute is updating only for particular store view

when we update through for our store , its working.

when we update through "**Default values**", its not working

in the image , you can see : **Default wide > English**

once we select that and update the attribute value, than its working fine. but

when we select "Default values" , than its not working.

it is dropdown attribute we are facing this problem. but for "textfield" attribute everything is working fine.

[image]

we are using following code :

**Phtml Code for Cod**

```
<td>

<?php $attribute = $products->getResource()->getAttribute('cod_available');?>
<?php if($attribute):?>
<?php $attribute_value = $attribute ->getFrontend()->getValue($products); ?>

<select id = "cod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" name= "cod[]" > 

<option value="0" <?php if($pro->getCodAvailable()==0) { echo "selected";} ?>>No</option> 
<option value="1"<?php if($pro->getCodAvailable()==1) { echo "selected";} ?>>Yes</option> 

</select> 

<?php endif; ?>

<input type="hidden" name="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" id="codcurr_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" value="<?php echo $products->getCod(); ?>" /> 

<p id="updatedcod_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" style = "display:none;color:red; position:relative; top:16px;">Updated</p>
<br/>

<button id="cod_reset_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" type="reset" class="cancel" onclick="hideResetCod('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>','<?php echo $products->getPrice(); ?>'); return false;">
<span><span><?php echo $helper->__('Cancel') ?></span></span>
</button>
</span>
</td>
```

**phtml code for all products**

```
<td>
<button id="update_button_<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>" class="button wk_mp_btn1" onclick="updateAllFields('<?php echo $products->getId(); ?>'); return false;" type="button"  >
<span><span style="font-size:12px;"><?php echo $helper->__('Update') ?></span></span>
</button>
</td>
```

**script for Cod**

```
function hideResetCod(product_id,codold) { 

var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuecod).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currcod).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}




function updateFieldCod(product_id) 
{ 
var codId = '#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedcod_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldCod/')?>'; 
$cod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
$currcod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
if($cod!=$currcod) {
$wk_jq(currcod).val($cod); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
}
```

**Script to update all product infromation**

```
function updateAllFields(product_id) {
        jQuery('#price_reset_button_'+product_id).css('display','none');
        if(jQuery("#price_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#curr_"+product_id).val())
              updateFieldPrice(product_id);

        if(jQuery("#specialprice_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#specialcurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldSpecialPrice(product_id);
            updateField(product_id);

        if(jQuery("#cod_"+product_id).val() != jQuery("#codcurr_"+product_id).val())
            updateFieldCod(product_id); 
            updateField(product_id);


            }
```

**Controller.php for Cod**

```
public function updateFieldCodAction(){
        Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);      
        $id= $this->getRequest()->getParam('id');
        $customerid=Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->getCustomerId();
        $collection_product = Mage::getModel('marketplace/product')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('mageproductid',array('eq'=>$id))->addFieldToFilter('userid',array('eq'=>$customerid));

        try{
        $upd_cod = $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($id);        
        $product->setData('cod_available',$upd_cod);
        $product->getResource()->saveAttribute($product,'cod_available');  
     //   $product->setCod($upd_cod);

        $product->save();

        echo $cod = $product->getCod();
        echo $name = $product->getName();

        $response['message'] = 'Your Product Is Been Sucessfully Updated';
        $this->getResponse()->setBody(Mage::helper('core')->jsonEncode($response)); 

        }catch(Exception $e){
        echo "Not Saving"; exit;    
        Mage::log($e->getMessage());
        }

      }
```

**controller.php for all product information**

```
public function massupdatesellerproAction(){
      if($this->getRequest()->isPost()){
        if(!$this->_validateFormKey()){
             $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');
        }
        $ids= $this->getRequest()->getParam('product_mass_update');
        $price= $this->getRequest()->getParam('price');
        $special= $this->getRequest()->getParam('specialprice');

        $cod= $this->getRequest()->getParam('cod');

        foreach ($ids as $key => $value) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($value);
    $product->setPrice($price[$key]);
    $product->setSpecialPrice($special[$key]);
    $product->setQty($qty[$key]);

    $product->setCodAvailable($cod[$key]);

$product->save();
        }
        Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addSuccess( Mage::helper('marketplace')->__('Products has been sucessfully deleted from your account'));
        $this->_redirect('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/myproductslist/');


    }}
```

Comment: baby this question needs debugging because it is not default magento feature

Comment: please help me how i can debug this ?

Comment: remove this code and check it is working from Controller.php for Cod `Mage::app()->setCurrentStore(Mage_Core_Model_App::ADMIN_STORE_ID);   `

Comment: i wiil check it.

Comment: @QaisarSatti it did't worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function hideResetCod(product_id,codold) { 

var qtyId='#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var editLink="#cod_edit_link_"+ product_id; 
var updateButton="#cod_update_button_"+ product_id; 
var valuecod="#valuecod_"+ product_id; 
var resetButton="#cod_reset_button_"+ product_id; 


$wk_jq(valuecod).show(); 
$wk_jq(qtyId).val( $wk_jq(currcod).val()); 
$wk_jq(editLink).show(); 

}




function updateFieldCod(product_id) 
{ 
var codId = '#cod_'+ product_id; 
var currcod='#codcurr_'+ product_id; 
var updatedqty = '#updatedcod_'+ product_id; 
var url ='<?php echo Mage::getUrl('marketplace/marketplaceaccount/updateFieldCod/')?>'; 
$cod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
$currcod = $wk_jq(codId).val(); 
if($cod!=$currcod) {
$wk_jq(currcod).val($cod); 
new Ajax.Request(url, { 
method: 'post', 

parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
//parameters: {id: product_id, cod: $cod}, 
onComplete: function (transport) { 
//alert(transport.responseText); 

jQuery(updatedqty).show().delay(2000).fadeOut(); 

} 
}); 
}
}
```